# Oracle decode alternative

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to replace 0 values with NA in the output. The solution i have tried is to use `DECODE`. but for expressions it gets too lengthy. similar to below

```
DECODE(round((A.DollarsunderAvgPrice/A.VolumeSales*100)
                /(E.DollarsunderAvgPrice/E.VolumeSales*100)
             ,3)
      ,0,
      'NA',
      round((A.DollarsunderAvgPrice/A.VolumeSales*100)
              /(E.DollarsunderAvgPrice/E.VolumeSales*100)
           ,3)
      )
```

So i am looking for an alternate solution. Ideally like below.

```
DECODE(VALUE,COMAPAREVALUE,COMPARE_TRUEVALUE)
```

if false VALUE itself.

Unlike the answers below I would like to avoid `Subquery`, `CTE` and even `case expressions` if possible. because the query already has lot many columns returned and has many similar expressions as above, So the query will get much bigger with it

Comment: This is something you should do in your GUI layer. 'NA' and the calculation result are not even of the same type, so don't do that in SQL. (You *could* convert the calculation result to string in SQL as you are doing implicitly already, but I don't recommend it.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for pointing this out, yeah the `DECODE` looked a bit off to me.

Comment: If you really think you *must* do this in SQL, here is a way: convert zero to null and null to 'NA'. `nvl(to_char(nullif(<expression>,0)),'NA')`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner GUI seems to be an overhead work for me in my case. The solution you have provided should really reduce the complexity though. Thanks !

Comment: Think this should also be answer as there is no builtin function available

Comment: Okay, I've posted this as an answer, for it may also help future readers to get a quick solution :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, this is nothing you should usually do in SQL, as SQL is meant to get you data only. If you want to display that data you would use some program or website where you could handle this. But for a quick solution you can use

```
nvl(to_char(nullif(<expression>,0)),'NA')
```

This converts zero to null first and then null to 'NA'. You may also want to specify a format in `TO_CHAR`.

Comment: Stole it under my nose :-)

Answer (score 2):

Prepare your data first then do `decode`

```
with d as (select round((A.DollarsunderAvgPrice/A.VolumeSales*100)/(E.DollarsunderAvgPrice/E.VolumeSales*100),3) val from your_table)
select decode(val, 0 , 'NA', val) from d;
```

Answer (score 1):

how about doing calculation in a subquery and apply decode outside:

```
select decode(x, 0, 'NA', to_char(x)) from
(select round((A.DollarsunderAvgPrice/A.VolumeSales*100)/(E.DollarsunderAvgPrice/E.VolumeSales*100),3) x
from my_table);
```

or a CTE:

```
with t as (select round((A.DollarsunderAvgPrice/A.VolumeSales*100)/(E.DollarsunderAvgPrice/E.VolumeSales*100),3) x
    from my_table)
select decode(x, 0, 'NA', to_char(x)) from t;
```

May be `CASE`:

```
with t as (select round((A.DollarsunderAvgPrice/A.VolumeSales*100)/(E.DollarsunderAvgPrice/E.VolumeSales*100),3) x
    from my_table)
select case when x = 0 then 'NA' else to_char(x) end from t;
```

<sub>P.S. - putting proper casts is a good practice such as `to_char()` when getting the result in above query</sub>

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT DECODE(X,0,'NA',X)
  FROM (SELECT round((A.DollarsunderAvgPrice/A.VolumeSales*100)/(E.DollarsunderAvgPrice/E.VolumeSales*100),3) AS X
        FROM dual);
```